# Prove the implication: $k$ is odd implies $k^n$ is odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

So far, I have my base case where  $ k = 2n+1 $ and $k^n \equiv (2n+1)^n$. Plugging in $1$ for $n$ gives me $3$, which is odd so the base case is true.

Now for the inductive hypothesis: Assume $P(n)$ is true

I want to prove the implication $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ via contraposition. So I would assume it is not the case $k^n$ is odd, so I assume $k^n$ is even. I would then rewrite $k^n=2l$ as it is equivalent to multiple of integer $l$.

I'm confused where to go from here though, so if someone can help me figure this out I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: There is no need to use contrapositives like that. Just do it directly. Prove or use the fact that the product of two odd numbers is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A notational note: you have $n$ as the exponent and in the representation of $k$, even though these do not need to be the same. So I will write $k=2m+1$. You do not need to use contraposition or anything fancy, just do straight induction on $n$ where $k$ is a fixed odd number.

For the induction step, you use the induction hypothesis which is that $k^n$ is odd, so $k^n=2m'+1$. Hence,
$$k^{n+1}=k^nk=(2m'+1)(2m+1)$$
Note, you will need to re-verify the base case using $k=2m+1$ and not $k=2n+1$ (although this is still trivial).

Answer (score 2):

You can't assume that $k=2n+1$ with $n$ being the power with which you raise $k$: they have nothing to do with each other.

Instead, simply stick to $k$ being some arbitrary odd integer, and do induction on $n$

So, the base case is where $n=1$, i.e $k^n=k^1=k$ is odd. Check!

For the step: assume $k^n$ is odd, and now show that $k^{n+1}$ is odd. Again, all you need is that $k$ is odd. Indeed, no proof by contrapositive here needed either: this is going to be direct and fairly simple.

Answer (score 2):

"About binomial theorem I am teeming with a lot of news."--from [*The Major General's Song*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj9v76K6orXAhVF12MKHZjICngQtwIIMjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DzSGWoXDFM64&usg=AOvVaw2NR3MfCmK7uHIPk4RrmR7b), *Pirates of Penzance*, Gilbert and Sullivan.

It can also be done using the binomial theorem.

If $k$ is odd, we have

$k = 2j + 1, \tag 1$

for some $j \in \Bbb Z$. Then

$k^n = (2j + 1)^n = \displaystyle \sum_0^n \dfrac{n!}{i!(n - i)!}(2j)^i(1)^{(n - i)}; \tag 2$

inspection of (2) reveals that every term with $i \ne 0$ contains a factor of $2j$, hence is divisible by $2$.  The $i = 0$ term is precisely $1$, hence we have

$ \displaystyle \sum_0^n \dfrac{n!}{i!(n - i)!}(2k)^i(1)^{(n - i)} = 2m + 1 \tag 3$

for some $m \in \Bbb Z$, whence $k^n$ is in fact, like our friend the Modern Major General, odd.

Be assured that, though not at the forefront, induction is by no means left out of this argument; how else prove the binomial theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the fundamental theorem of algebra. Any number n can be written as a product of primes $n = p_1p_2p_3...p_k$ where $p_i  \le p_{i+1}$

So if n is odd, 2 does not divide n, so $p_i \ne 2$  $\forall 0 \le i \le k$

So take $n^m$. $$n^m=p_1^m p_2^m...p_k^m \text{ where } p_i \ne 2  \forall 0 \le i \le k$$

So, 2 does not divide $n^m$

Answer (score 0):

Another fancy proof using Bezout;

$k$ is odd $\iff\gcd(k,2)=1\iff \exists (u,v)\in\mathbb Z^2\mid uk+2v=1$

Let's consider the following induction relation $P(n): u^nk^n+2v\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} u^ik^i\right)=1$

$P(1)$ is true, as shown in the beginning.

Now assuming $P(n)$ then

$1=u^nk^n+2v\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} u^ik^i\right)=u^nk^n\underbrace{(uk+2v)}_{=1}+2v\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} u^ik^i\right)=u^{n+1}k^{n+1}+2v\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} u^ik^i\right)$

So $P(n+1)$ is verified and the induction proof is completed.

Thus $\forall n\ge 1, \exists (a,b)\mid ak^n+2b=1\iff \gcd(k^n,2)=1\iff k^n\text{ is odd}$